# xcode 4 The selected run destination is not valid for this action

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, xcode4, provisioning-profile

hello there i have a problem that  that prevents me debuging in xcode 4 
my problem is that i wanted to create a environment to test my apps on my ipad. when i re-searched about the topic i came across this tutorial: [Iphone Dev-Wiki](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode)
I have done everything as said (looked for the validity of this method its dates are valid)
but after im done with the steps and run my app it gives me `The selected run destination is not valid for this action` Error because suddenly the only build destination i have is the Mac 64-bit.

i tried to change the sdk too but there are no other option than the Mac 64-bit
[image: here is a snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

In this screen go to your Targets, then Summary, and try to select your Device to Universal, or which one you need to